# Android CryptoObject usage in fingerprint

Tags: android, cryptography, fingerprint

In Android fingerprint sample code [FingerprintDialog](http://developer.android.com/samples/FingerprintDialog/index.html), the method that starts fingerprint hardware [FingerprintManager#authenticate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.html#authenticate(android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.CryptoObject,%20android.os.CancellationSignal,%20int,%20android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback,%20android.os.Handler)) takes a parameter of [FingerprintManager.CryptoObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.CryptoObject.html). According to the documentation, it's the `object associated with the call or null if none required`. The description is still not clear for me. Would someone explain when I should or should not use crypto Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The FingerprintDialog sample provided in the Android Samples is a bit dense so let's break down what's happening:

1. Configure and generate cryptographic Keys.  In this step you can specify that the Key can only be used if `KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.setAuthenticated(true)`.
2. Initialize a Cipher object with the cipherMode (encrypt/decrypt) and the Key generated from Step 1
3. Initialize a `FingerprintCrypto.CryptoObject()` with the Cipher from Step 2
4. Start the Fingerprint scanner and pass in the CryptoObject from step 3 by calling `FingerprintManager.authenticate()`
5. User successfully authenticates with their fingerprint.  The Android OS will set the "authenticated" bit in the Key from 0 to 1.
6. Now that the key has been authenticated for use, it can be used to do any crypto operation by calling `Cipher.doFinal()`.

If you try to modify step 4 by passing in `null` to `FingerprintManager.authenticate()`, then step 6 will fail because you have not been authenticated to use the key.

Hope that helps.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your help. Regarding step 1, I assumed you meant `KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder.setUserAuthenticationRequired(boolean required)`. I tried passing null in step 4 before already. This time I tried to set step 1 to false and was able to call `Cipher.doFinal()` with result returned even before fingerprint authentication. The key has nothing to do with fingerprint authentication flow, it's just part of the sample code to demonstrate how to authenticate the use of the key.

Comment: But the other question is, why do I have to authenticate the key that I create myself within the same program?

Comment: By default the Keys in the Keystore can be used without any authentication.  If you call setUserAuthenticationRequired with true then you have to use your fingerprint to use the key.

Comment: Yes, I figured out that part. But when do I want to call `setUserAuthenticationRequired` with true?

Comment: I'm not a security expert but I would say that if you want to make it as hard as possible for an attacker to decrypt your stuff then setting setUserAuthenticationRequired to true would be a good idea.